# Is there a French language character map?

Tags: support, feature-request, characters

[image]
I'm noticing that my browser isn't always showing all the characters from questions and responses.  Is there any chance that the site creates a "character map" page for users to verify if their web browser is displaying all characters correctly?

Example:
[image]é

Comment: A solution might be to add a fallback font (if there is one providing blank glyphs as narrow no-break spaces on the offending OS, which must be an old Windows in this case).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez, I think it's your `nnbsp`'s, Windows doesn't like them either - they get displayed as squares in the TaskBar.

Comment: @Benjol: Those `nnbsp`'s are not mine ; this character is in Unicode 3.0 (that is year 1999), how come *your* Windows don't know it ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez, [dunno](http://stackapps.com/questions/2569/convert-ctrl-space-to-non-break-space-for-flu/2583#2583)

Comment: That's because [Windows (at least XP) does not know the Unicode narrow non-breakable space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595365/how-to-render-narrow-non-breaking-spaces-in-html-for-windows)

Comment: Good ol' [ALT+0151], always playful with OSes.

Comment: @RomainVALERI Oh, you mean AltGr + Shift + Space?

Answer (score 10):

#### Diacritics

- e acute: é É
- a grave: à À
- e grave: è È
- u grave: ù Ù
- a circumflex: â Â
- e circumflex: ê Ê
- i circumflex: î Î
- o circumflex: ô Ô
- u circumflex: û Û
- e dieresis: ë Ë
- i dieresis: ï Ï
- u dieresis: ü Ü
- y dieresis: ÿ Ÿ
- c cedilla: ç Ç

#### Ligatures

- oe ligature: œ Œ
- ae ligature: æ Æ

#### Special chars

- guillemets: « »
- en dash: –
- em dash: —
- ellipsis: …

#### Spaces

<sub>(Between ")</sub>

- Unbreakable space: " "
- Thin unbreakable space: " "
- en space: " "
- em space: " "

#### Phonetics

If you can read the two tables [here](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prononciation_du_fran%C3%A7ais#Prononciation_des_graph.C3.A8mes) you should be fine.

- Consonants: ʃ (ch), ɲ (gn), ʒ (j), ŋ (ng), ʁ (r); also the semi-vowel ɥ (u')
- Vowels: ɑ (posterior a), ø (most closed eu), œ (less closed eu), ə (central vowel, so-called *e muet*), ɛ (è), ɔ (open o)
- Nasal vowels (ɑ/ɛ/ɔ/œ with a tilde above): ɑ̃ (an/en), ɛ̃ (in/en), ɔ̃ (on), œ̃ (un)

Answer (score 3):

A little poll, just to have a clue about what we should do about narrow no-break spaces.

Is the space before the question mark displayed correctly at the end of this french sentence:

> L'espace est-elle affichée correctement avant ce point d'interrogation ?

For comparison purposes, here is the same sentence with no space, normal space and normal non-breaking space:

> L'espace est-elle affichée correctement avant ce point d'interrogation? (no space)
>   L'espace est-elle affichée correctement avant ce point d'interrogation ? (normal space)
>   L'espace est-elle affichée correctement avant ce point d'interrogation ? (normal non-breaking space)

If you want to test it with question titles, e.g. for window titlebar behavior, try [Alternatives à la finale « -é » tonique dans « Chanté-je juste ? »](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/120/82)

Please fill in your browser information here, if someone hasn't already reported the status:

- It works, I see a narrow space:

  - Firefox: 3.0.4/Fedora [chepseskaf]; 3.6/Linux Ubuntu [Unfrancophone]; {4,…,16}/Linux [Gilles,Stéphane,Evpok]; {3.5,5,…,14}/WinXP [Gilles, Evpok]; 3.6.3/Mac OS 10.4.11 [Joubarc]; 3.6.11/Win7 [Evpok]; 32.0a2/WinXP [Sifu]
  - Chrome: 8/WinXP [Gilles]; 14/Linux [Gilles]; 14/Win7 [chepseskaf]; 16/Win7 [chepseskaf]
  - IE: IE8 (8.0.7601.17514) / Windows 7 enterprise SP1 [Joubarc]
  - Safari: 4.1.3/Mac OS 10.4.11 [Joubarc]
  - Opera: 11.52/WinXP [Stamm]
- It doesn't work, I see a big square or other strange glyph:

  - IE: IE8/WinXP [Gilles, Sifu];
  - Android 2.2.1 default Browser app [Joubarc]
  - Firefox: 5/WinXP [chepseskaf]
  - Chrome: 15/WinXP [chepseskaf]; 36/WinXP [Sifu]
- It doesn't work, I see a normal space
- It doesn't work, I see a very wide space:

  - Firefox {10.0a1, 11.0a1}/Kubuntu 11.10 [EVpok]
  - Firefox {3.6.22, 12.0}/Linux RHEL5.5 [Unfrancophone]
- It doesn't work, I see no space:

  - Safari 5.1, Mac OS 10.6 [F’x]

---

And if you have some spare minutes, the developers might send you free cookies if you file a bug.

- Firefox : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org
- Chrome and Chromium : https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list
- Opera : https://bugs.opera.com/wizard/
- Konqueror : https://bugs.kde.org/
- Safari : https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/

Comment: Works for me in FFx at work and at home, but doesn't paste well into Word (FWIW), and shows squares in Windows XP Taskbar (http://stackapps.com/questions/2569/convert-ctrl-space-to-non-break-space-for-flu/2583#2583)

Comment: I just noticed that it doesn't necessarily shown in the edit pane even if it renders properly.

Comment: Why not use a simple non-breaking space?

Comment: @chepseska: To comply with usual French typography usages. And because an orphan guillemet is insufferably sad.

Comment: Possibly an ANSI/Unicode issue?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO The problem should really be solved server side. It is out of question to ask whoever visit the site to tweak with charset and maybe install some extra fonts.

Comment: I don't necessary agree.If we respect standards, there is no reason to have a normal space instead of non-breakable space because some non-conforming browsers/OS are around.

Comment: Actually it seems that most of the problems are browser bugs. I didn't realize this before.

Answer (score 0):

Heureusement qu'on a pas trop de signes diacritiques en français. Sinon on pourrait avoir des probl`̴̵̶̷̸̡̢̧̨̛̖̗̘̙̜̝̞̟̠̣̤̥̦̩̪̫̬̭̮̯̰̱̲̳̹̺̻̼͇͈͉͍͎̀́̂̃̄̅̆̇̈̉̊̋̌̍̎̏̐̑̒̓̔̽̾̿̀́͂̓̈́͆͊͋͌̕̚ͅ͏͓͔͕͖͙͚͐͑͒͗͛͘͜͟͢͝͞͠͡mes...